# Bulk trashing post 'fails'

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, trash

I want to bulk delete child posts of a custom post type, and I've made it work. I'm in class context:

```
// In a register method which registers all hooks.
add_action( 'wp_trash_post', [ $this, 'delete_child_posts' ], 10 );

public function delete_child_posts( int $post_id ) {
  $current_post = get_post( $post_id );

  // Check if current post is in the documentation post type.
  if ( $current_post->post_type !== 'documentation' ) {
    return;
  }

  // Only trigger when deleting parent post.
  if ( $current_post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
    return;
  }

  $child_pages = [
    'post_parent' => $post_id,
  ];

  $children = get_children( $child_pages );

  if ( empty( $children ) ) {
    return;
  }

  foreach ( $children as $child_post ) {
    wp_trash_post( $child_post->ID );
  }
}
```

This works super when I'm deleting parent post, or a single post (even a child).

But if I select the parent and the children posts, and try to delete them I'll get

> Error in moving to Trash.

I go back and I see the posts, then refresh the browser, and they are in the trash.

So, what happens is: the parent post is deleted, the logic goes through, and child posts are trashed in the foreach loop. Then the first child goes in the hook callback since it's being trashed and this action will be triggered, I can see the post ID, and it doesn't pass the

```
// Only trigger when deleting parent post.
if ( $current_post->post_parent !== 0 ) {
  return;
}
```

check. So the action should exit and that's that. But I get an error. I tried returning post id, post object null, checking if the post status is `trash`, but I always get an error.

What am I missing?

Comment: The way I see it happening here is that the parent is trashed, and as you have it designed it goes recursively 1 layer deep through all of the children and trashes them.

Then, the initial bulk action you started moves onto the next post -- one of the children...which of course is already trashed. I imagine your post_parent !== 0 check is working. But just because *you* don't delete the post isn't stopping WP from deleting it. Basically you're calling wp_trash_post twice on the same post -- once via the bulk delete, and again via its parent's iteration of your function here.

Comment: But even though the post is trashed (`post_type` = `trash`), the post parent is still the original one (in the database, I've checked) so it's odd that it fails here.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm hooking to actions that are originally in `wp_trash_post` function, and that's causing the issue.

Comment: Perhaps, I haven't looked into that idea. But do keep in mind that error shows up if the wp_trash_post function returns false. The 3rd condition of the function checks if the post_status is already "trash", and then returns false if it is.So if you try to trash a trashed post, you get that message.

Comment: 3rd argument of which function? Sorry, not sure I followed correctly

Comment: The third condition, not argument, of wp_trash_post. Basically I just mean when you call that function, the third thing it does is check if the post is already trashed. If it is, it gives back that error message you see.

Comment: Oh this part: `if ( 'trash' === $post->post_status ) { return false; }`, yeah, that could be the issue, but I don't think I can avoid it. I tried using `wp_post_delete` with `false` argument, but that didn't work...

Comment: Don't see anything super easy. Not much you can modify with how WP bulk deletes them. You can modify yours but yours runs first and is blind to what's happening elsewhere. Wonder if there's a way to make your code execute later, then it could check to see if each post is already trashed. Maybe AJAX, or storing a list of "posts to delete" in the db and running it on the next WP page load instead of right when its registered...nothing great here sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I'll have to live with it until I find a different solution... Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The only other thought I had was separating out *your* deletion from the default deletion. Instead of always deleting the children admin-wide, just add a new link on post list pages like "delete with children" and only run your code there. Then it won't compete with the default delete or the default bulk delete.

Comment: This is actually not a bad idea!